# how to print 2d array in laravel 5.4.12 by dd();?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

please help me to solve this problem that how to **die and dump** 2D array in laravel and count array in an array.. i tried this but not working

```
$arr=collect($request->input('title['+$i+']'));
    dd($arr->count());
```

also tried this code

```
$arr=collect($request->input('title[0]'));
    dd($arr->count());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not say that you need to count them in your questions but here you go:

**The aray:**

```
  $arrayname= array(
            array('a', 'b', 'c'),
            array('r', 't','y', 'u'),
        );
```

**The function**

```
    for ($i=0;  $i < count($arrayname); $i++){
        $singlearray[$i]= count($arrayname[$i]);
    }
```

**Result**

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => 3
  1 => 4
]
```

Answer (score 1):

`dd($request->all())` will display contents of the array.

If you want to see the title, do this:

```
dd($request->title);
```

Comment: but i want to count them  and post my data by for loop

Comment: @JamalAhmad well, you didn't asked about this in your question.

Answer (score 1):

try to use:

`echo count($arr);
dd($arr);`

or

`echo count($arr);
print_r($arr);
die;`

Comment: brother i want to count array in an array.. suppose how many titles have on single index..

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = $request->all();
$flatArray = [];
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($a));
foreach($it as $v) {
  $array[] = $v;
}
dd(count($flatArray));
```

Resource:
[How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 0):

i get it from the other site... [Answer here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-print-2d-array-in-laravel-5412-by-dd)

`dd(count(request('title')[0]));
dd(count(request('title')['age']));`